# Use NSPredicate to filter by object particular attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having an array with collection custom objects.

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *customerName;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *departmentName;

DataClass *dataClass = [[DataClass alloc]init];
dataClass.customerName = @"John";
dataClass.departmentName = @"Electricals";
[inputArray addObject: dataClass];
DataClass *dataClass = [[DataClass alloc]init];
dataClass.customerName = @"Ezhil";
dataClass.departmentName = @"Electronics";
[inputArray addObject: dataClass];
```

Now I want to filter the department name alone in a new array. After filtering I want "Electrical" and "Electronics" in a array. How can I achieve this using NSPredicate?

Comment: `valueForKey:` or `valueForKeyPath:` could do the trick. I don't think that `NSPredicate` is designed for this.

Comment: Currently I am using valueForKey but it takes more time when collection is above ten thousand items.

Comment: "ten thousand items." All theses in RAM? Or are you using a Database? CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use NSPredicate in the way you want

because `dataClass.customerName = @"John";
dataClass.departmentName = @"Electricals";`

is one single object

we can use NSPredicate if you want to "Fetch all objects having department name = Electricals"

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *filtered = [inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(key == %@)", currentKeyName]];
```

currentKeyName is the String with key Name.
Likewise you can filter the array with Desired Predicate.